# Is it possible to have an transparent acrylic blur effect in WPF on part of the window?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I would like to have a transparent window that can be clicked through, and then to be able to blur off parts of it so that the content behind from other apps and the desktop are selectively blurred. In the end I want to have a clear rectangle in the middle and blur around the outside like this:

[image]

The parts that are blurred do not have to let clicks pass through, but the center still should.

There are a few similar questions to this but they do not cover the current situation for the following reasons:

Most of the solutions don't appear to work with dotnet core 5
Most of the solutions either transparently blur the whole window (i.e. the desktop behind the window), or the parts of the application the blurred control overlaps, or the control itself. None of them blur the desktop content behind without affecting the whole window.

Yes I could probably make this shape with 4 chromeless windows but I am hoping I don't have to do that.

Comment: an opacitiymask on your window should work

Comment: Please no external image sources ...

Comment: @DenisSchaf I am using an opacity mask already, I want to know if I can get a blur effect.

Comment: the blurring of outside content is not natively in WPF depending on what you want to do setting the window background to white and low opacity might do the trick, other than that you can reffer to this source https://medium.com/@walterlv/3-ways-to-create-a-window-with-blurring-background-on-windows-10-5c2fe3fa1eda

Comment: I already saw that article. The first two options are obviously not valid based on my requirements, the third is the one I have been trying to get working. Unfortunately I can't work out what nuget package will give me Acrylic brush on WPF. As far as I can tell it is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as I can tell the answer is: No

I managed to get something sort of like this working using the code from https://github.com/riverar/sample-win32-acrylicblur but for one it is kind of ugly as it only enables making a blur background on a window, and no controls of any kind can be shown on that window. So I created 4 windows and tile them around the area in the middle. The issue with that is that the seams between the window are quite obvious which is not ideal. [image]

To sum up, wpf in .net core does not appear support blurring of the background in anything but the most primitive way.